# Rows to colum on Excel by id

Tags: excel, rows

Good morning, 
I want to ask a question about excel. I have this table. And what I want to switch rows to a column by conserving the id.  Find example below:

```
id  year    topic
1   2001    peras // manzanas   
2   2002    peras // manzanas   
3   2003    peras // manzanas // platano    
4   2004    peras // manzanas // platano    
5   2005    peras // manzanas // platano    
6   2006    peras // manzanas
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
id  Col2
1 peras
1 manzanas
2 peras
2 manzanas
3 peras
3 manzanas
3 platano
```

I have checked on the forum different examples with index function but it did not work. 
any suggestion would be very welcome!
Best,

Comment: I *think* you will need `VBA` for this

Comment: Is `peras // manzanas` all in a single cell?  Or are you indicating that `peras` and `manzanas` are in separate cells in the same row(s)?

Answer (score 0):

At first you need split a cell "topic" by using menu "Data" -> "Text to column".

Then select data cells without headers and use this macros:

```
Sub CopyFilledRows()
 On Error Resume Next
    new_row = 1
    Set Rng = Application.Selection
    With Sheets(2)
        For r = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
            For c = 3 To Rng.Columns.Count
                If Rng.Cells(r, c) <> "" Then
                    .Cells(new_row, 1) = Rng.Cells(r, 1)
                    .Cells(new_row, 2) = Rng.Cells(r, c)
                    new_row = new_row + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Now sheet 2 contains what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not good advice. There are a few issues with your code: Firstly, you should always use `Option Explicit`.. you are missing some declarations (wont go into why that's bad, there are a lot of examples of that). When you set your `Rng`, you are using `Application.Selection`.. you shouldn't use selected items as you are than assuming that the selection is the one you want (again may examples of that available). You don't need `new_row`, you can just use `r` instead. Have a look into how to qualify your sheets and objects. Hope that helps